# How to construct Json-patch payload to call PATCH endpoint

Tags: java, json-patch

Library used: `com.github.fge.jsonpatch`
And I have one PATCH endpoint which accepts the String of json-patch operations.

`public Employee patchEmployee(String patchOperations, String empId);`

This method then does the required conversion to JsonPatch and all the necessary steps to apply the patch. This part is working fine when an array of Json-patch operations is sent to it in string format as a payload.

But to call this API from a rest client, I need to construct the array of json-patch operations in String format.

I am trying to use the JsonPatchOperation like:
 `JsonPatchOperation replaceName = new ReplaceOperation(new JsonPointer("/name"), nameNode);`
`JsonPatchOperation replaceSubject = new ReplaceOperation(new JsonPointer("/subject"), subjectNode);`

Using this method I can apply the operations to the Employee object directly, but as the endpoint accepts the String, I am not getting how to convert these operations to String format like:

```
[
    {"op": "replace", "path": "/name","value":"John" },
    {"op": "replace", "path": "/subject","value":"Science" }
]
```

Is there any way we can construct this payload apart from manually creating the Json string?